# Converting time String to Long generates wrong value

Tags: java, android

I have a time String "00:01:00". When I convert it to long by SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss), I'm getting 10860000 milliseconds, equivalent to 03:01:00.

For "00:59:00" I'm getting "03:57:00", so I don't know what's happening but it's adding 3hours to my milliseconds.

Code:

```
String time = String.format("%02d",hourOfDay) + ":" + String.format("%02d", minute) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds);

tvTimer.setText(time);

try {
     DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
     Time timeValue = new Time(formatter.parse(time).getTime());

     long initTimer = timeValue.getTime
} catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

CountDownTimer:

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(initTimer, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long l) {

                        long secondsInMilli = initTimer / 1000;
                        long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli / 60;
                        long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli / 60;

                        long elapsedSeconds = secondsInMilli % 60;
                        long elapsedMinutes = minutesInMilli % 60;
                        long elapsedHours = hoursInMilli % 60;

                        tvTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", elapsedHours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", elapsedMinutes) +":" + String.format("%02d", elapsedSeconds));
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a time zone problem. The string "00:01:00" does not specify a world time, because there is no time zone on it. The parsing will be done on some default time zone, and your offset is evidently 3 (mine seems to be -5).

If you parse "00:01:00 GMT" with ("HH:mm:ss z"), you get the 60000 milliseconds you expect.

Comment: Ok! Worked fine! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Since you're new to StackOverflow: If you find any answer (or any question) helpful, you can upvote it -- this helps other people know that it is helpful, and is a tiny reward for the person posting helpful information. If you post a question, it is usual not only to upvote any helpful response, but to mark the first response that answers your question as "the answer"; this marks the *question* as having been answered, and also gives points to the person answering. It also makes it more likely that any other questions you ask will be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Timezone after instantiating the formatter, as next:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

or if you need the local time zone then:

```
formatter.setTimeZone(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone());
```

Comment: Ok! Worked fine! Thanks!